# Почему после изменений данных в кэше- получаю неактуальные данные при попытке вернуть лист?

Tags: java, spring, кэширование

После любой crud операции с кэшом получаю неактуальные данные при попытке вернуть List всех сущностей(метод getAllProxyConfigurations). Почему это может происходить и как это исправить?

При чем другие методы отображают актуальную информацию

```
 @Cacheable("configuration")
    public List<Configuration> getAllProxyConfigurations() {
        return repository.getAllConfigurations();
}

   @Cacheable(value = "configuration", key = "#root.target.getConfigurationById(#id).serverId")
    public Configuration getConfigurationById(Long id) {
...
   return configuration;
}

 @CachePut(value = "configuration", key = "#configuration.serverId", condition = "#result.id != null")
    public Configuration addOrUpdateConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
   return configuration;
}

   @Cacheable(value = "configuration", key = "#serverId")
    public Configuration getConfigurationByServerId(String serverId) {...
   return configuration;
}

   @CacheEvict(value = "configuration", key = "#root.target.getConfigurationById(#id).serverId")
    public void deleteConfigurationById(Long id) {
...
}
```

Comment: А какие данные актуальные?

Comment: @RomanC данные, которые симметричы данных в бд. Как уже указал выше- остальные кэш-методы работают корректно. 
Как я понимаю дело с ключом по умолчанию, который не переопределен в методе getAllProxyConfigurations(). Осталось разобраться как его можно переопределить

Comment: Когда разберёмся, то напиши ответ, или Измени вопрос так, чтобы было понятно где и что вызвало трудности и/или ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На момент создания вопроса - не понимал внутренних процессов кэширования. 
В spring.cache лежит лист из мап, мапы- это кэши,которые называем в параметрах аннотаций, например: @Cacheable(value/name/cacheNames="cache_name")
Я хотел ложить в кэш возвращенный лист и работать с эллементами данного листа. 
Но это в корне не правильно, так как (в моем случае) в мэпу, в одну ячейку ложился бы весь лист лист из эллементов, а в остальные ячейки (из других методов) эллементы, ключами которых выступали бы значения serverId и id. То есть обращение происходило к совершенно разным эллементам.

Поэтму, было принято решение сделать неколько кэшей: для всех эллементов "config_all", для единичных "config_serverId" и "config_id"(так как использовать запись, вроде такой не логично: "#root.target.getConfigurationById(#id).serverId" по причине того, что в любом случае вызывался метод getConfigurationById).

Итог: Убрал аннотации @CachePut на обновление- заменил на @Cacheable. Это позволяет держать в кэше актуальные данные без головной боли